# Calculating Next Quarterly Cycle

Tags: sql-server, date, datepart

I have a set of data with start dates.  A cycle runs every quarter according to the start date. (ex. start date of 3/15/15, the cycle runs 3/15/17, 6/15/17, 9/15/17, etc). I am having issues getting this to calculate the next cycle date correctly

```
when datepart(mm,getdate()) <= datepart(mm, STARTDATE) and datepart(dd,getdate()) < datepart(dd, STARTDATE) then cast(dateadd(mm, (datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate())%3), dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate()),STARTDATE))as date)

when datepart(mm,getdate()) <= datepart(mm, STARTDATE) and datepart(dd,getdate()) > datepart(dd, STARTDATE) then cast(dateadd(mm, 3-(datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate())%3), dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate()),STARTDATE))as date)

when datepart(mm,getdate()) >= datepart(mm, STARTDATE) and datepart(dd,getdate()) <= datepart(dd, STARTDATE) then cast(dateadd(mm, 3-(datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate())%3), dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate()),STARTDATE))as date)

when  datepart(mm,getdate()) >= datepart(mm, STARTDATE) and datepart(dd,getdate()) >= datepart(dd, STARTDATE) then cast(dateadd(mm, 3+(datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate())%3), dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, STARTDATE,getdate()),STARTDATE))as date)
```

Here are my results: Some are correct, some are not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
ID| Start Date| |Next Date|
1|  3/10/2015|  7/10/2017|
2|  6/3/2009|   9/3/2017|
3|  9/28/2014|  6/28/2017|
4|  9/1/2016|   9/1/2017|
5|  6/1/2015|   6/1/2018|
6|  3/15/2017|  7/15/2017|
7|  3/15/2017|  3/15/2018|
8|  3/24/2015|  6/24/2017|
9|  3/1/2016|   3/1/2018|
10| 9/6/2012|   7/6/2017|
```

Comment: Datepart has a quarter argument (q or qq) that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Test Data set:

```
DECLARE @dlist as TABLE(startDate datetime)
INSERT INTO @dlist VALUES ('1/1/2010'),('2/22/2011'),('4/2/2015'),('11/1/2014'),('9/9/2019')
```

Then try a query like this.  Future dates are a bit funny, so you'll have to work around that with some case statements if it's going to be an issue.

```
SELECT
    startDate
    , DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,startDate, GETDATE()) + 1, startDate) as nextDate
FROM
    @dlist
```

Results:

```
startDate    nextDate
------------------------
2010-01-01   2017-07-01
2011-02-22   2017-08-22
2015-04-02   2017-07-02
2014-11-01   2017-08-01
2019-09-09   2017-09-09
```